# How can I run old versions of Airflow using docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

Basically I need to install and run an old version of Airflow (1.10.14) to maintain a legacy project, but installing it locally poses a series of challenges (e.g: something may go wrong and I end up with a broken system). So I'm trying to run an old version of Airflow using docker/docker-compose. The problem is that apparently, running Airflow using docker wasn't a thing back when version 1.10.14 was released and while this link: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.7.0/docker-compose.yaml is valid (and definitely works right out-of-the-box), this one https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.14/docker-compose.yaml is not.
What I'm trying to do is to use a custom docker-compose file, but I'm having trouble with it:

```yaml
  version: '3'
  x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  image: apache/airflow:1.10.14
  environment:
    - AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR=CeleryExecutor
    - AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    - AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND=db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    - AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL=redis://:@redis:6379/0
    - AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY=FB0o_zt4e3Ziq3LdUUO7F2Z95cvFFx16hU8jTeR1ASM=
    - AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION=True
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./airflow-data/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./airflow-data/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  depends_on:
    redis:
    condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
    condition: service_healthy

  services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.5
    environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: airflow
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
    POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
    - ./airflow-data/postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
    test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
    interval: 30s
    retries: 5
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
    - 6379:6379
    healthcheck:
    test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
    interval: 5s
    timeout: 30s
    retries: 50
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    << : *airflow-common
    user: "airflow"
    command: webserver
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
    test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
    interval: 10s
    timeout: 10s
    retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-scheduler:
    << : *airflow-common
    user: "airflow"
    command: scheduler
    restart: always

  airflow-worker:
    << : *airflow-common
    user: "airflow"
    command: worker
    restart: always

  airflow-init:
    << : *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    user: "airflow"
    command:
    - -c
    - airflow list_users || (
      airflow initdb &&
      airflow create_user
      --role Admin
      --username airflow
      --password airflow
      --email airflow@airflow.com
      --firstname airflow
      --lastname airflow
      )
    restart: on-failure

  flower:
    << : *airflow-common
    user: "airflow"
    command: flower
    ports:
    - 5555:5555
    healthcheck:
    test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/healthcheck"]
    interval: 10s
    timeout: 10s
    retries: 5
    restart: always
```

when I run `docker-compose up` I keep getting permission issues, more specifically, I keep getting an error saying `Unable to configure handler 'processor': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/airflow/logs/scheduler'`. Of course the first thing I tried was to grant the require permissions, so I ran `echo -e "AIRFLOW_UID=$(id -u)\nAIRFLOW_GID=0" > .env`

Here's what ended up in my .env file:

```
AIRFLOW_UID=1004
AIRFLOW_GID=0
```

I'm kind of a docker noob, found this docker-compose file online and adapted it, so I might be doing weird stuff and that's why I came for help. I'm on Ubuntu, running python3.8 and have sudo permissions, if that's of any help.

Can someone please offer some insight on what I'm doing wrong? Do you guys think I should just abandon the idea of using Docker here and go for the official way (local) of installing it?

Thanks.

Comment: so is `/opt/airflow/logs/scheduler` i.e. `./airflow-data/logs` directory accessible by 1004 user?

Comment: I just figured this problem out. I just needed to replace the user name from "airflow" to "${AIRFLOW_UID:-1004}:0". The permission errors stopped, but new ones appeared and I'll ask them in another question